# MVC4 ActionLink without parameters points to current path

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis, actionlink, html.actionlink

I have a MVC4 Index page that have the following links:

```
@Html.ActionLink("FOO", "Index", "Mil", new { year = String.Empty, id = String.Empty }, null)
@Html.ActionLink("BAR", "Index", "Euro", new { year = String.Empty, id = String.Empty }, null)
```

But oddly both turn into a hyperlink to the *CURRENT* path (i.e. if we are at **domain/Euro/2016/1** both link to this address), instead of pointing to the specified controller.

Everything normal in **RouteConfig**:

```
routes.MapRoute(
             name: "Default",
             url: "{controller}/{year}/{id}",
             defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", year = UrlParameter.Optional, id = UrlParameter.Optional }
         );
```

The Controllers/Actions exist and work fine:

**EuroController**:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? year, int? id)
 {
    ...
 }
```

What can be causing this odd behavior?

**EDIT:**

If i pass year parameter, works fine: `@Html.ActionLink("FOO", "Index", "Mil", new { year = 666, id = String.Empty }, null)` correctly points to **domain/Mil/666**.

Comment: Probably not the issue, but only the last parameter can be marked as `UrlParameter.Optional`

Comment: I edited my question. That's not the solution but surely is related. I changed `year=UrlParameter.Optional` in Routes to `year=""` as you suggested but the problem remained.

Comment: either use `null` ie: `@Html.ActionLink("FOO", "Index", "Mil", new { year = null, id = null }, null)` or remove them all together, ie: `@Html.ActionLink("FOO", "Index", "Mil", null, null)`

Comment: @Nkrosi Neither of the two links you suggested worked.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to make it work by adding this **New** route after the Default one.

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{year}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", year = "", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                 );
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "New",
                url: "{controller}/{year}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", year = UrlParameter.Optional }
                 );
```

All the following links produce the desired effect:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Euro 2014", "Index", "Euro", new { year = 2014 }, null)
@Html.ActionLink("Euro 2015", "Index", "Euro", new { year = 2015, id = String.Empty }, null)
@Html.ActionLink("Euro 2016", "Index", "Euro", new { year = DateTime.Now.Year, id = "" }, null)
@Html.ActionLink("Back to Euro", "Index", "Euro", new { year = String.Empty }, null)
```